# How does cLock retrieve the weather information?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clock, firewall, weather

I'm running a Cyanogenmod 12.1 nightly with [AFWall](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) 2.0.0 installed. AFWall seems to work as expected, except for the *Yahoo! Weather* service integrated in the cLock widget!? Even if the firewall is enabled without any exceptions I am able to refresh the weather and retrieve possible locations.
This, however, is only possible using the *Yahoo! Weather* service. If I switch to the *OpenWeatherMap* service I am not able to update the weather information..

I already installed a network monitor ([Network Log](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.googlecode.networklog)), but the log doesn't record any 'suspicious' traffic..
I was able to block the *Yahoo! Weather* service using [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway) together with a [selfmade hosts-list](https://stuff.lesscomplex.org/adaway.txt).

However, I'm currently a bit lost. How does the cLock retrieve the weather information from *Yahoo! Weather*? Why is AFWall not able to block it? And why don't I see anything in the Network Log tool?